# How to search only in selective log streams in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

If my search pattern is *search_pattern* and the log group contains many log streams, but I am only interested in the ones with a certain prefix, is there a way to filter to log streams to search from instead of searching the entire log stream using `Search Log Stream` option?
Illustration:
Say my log group contains:
student-logs-A
student-logs-B
student-logs-C
teacher-logs-A
teacher-logs-B
teacher-logs-C
management-logs-A
management-logs-B
management-logs-C

I want to search for pattern *search_pattern* only in log streams starting from 'student-logs'? AWS cli or Console, any solution is okay.

Answer (score 0):

From the AWS [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/filter-log-events.html), the `filter-log-events` accepts a list of log streams:

```
aws logs filter-log-events --log-group-name my-group --log-stream-names LIST_OF_STREAMS_TO_SEARCH --filter-pattern VALID_METRIC_FILTER_PATTERN
```

If you don't want to provide a list, it also accepts a prefix:

```
aws logs filter-log-events --log-group-name my-group --log-stream-name-prefix PREFIX --filter-pattern VALID_METRIC_FILTER_PATTERN
```